# GET request to C9 API

Tags: xcode, api, cloud9-ide, postman

I am hosting an API on c9.io , I can GET my data by visiting the URL on a browser, but when I request it from XCode or Postman it returns HTML. Any reason why and how to fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm2PL.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set the content-type header appropriately for the type of data you are expecting to receive (ensure the service is able to negotiate the content-type you choose):

[image]

A little more info on MIME types if you need it...[Mime types](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)